# poner dos div uno al lado del otro con estilo dentro del div

Tags: html

Este es mi código, tengo otro código igual a este, necesito que se ubiquen 2 input y al lado dos input, actualmente tengo dos input y abajo dos input.

Intente varias cosas ya como por ejemplo ponerle un row al div que contiene dos input y al div que contiene los otros dos input, también intente ponerlo con float.

```
<div style= "display: inline-block" class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group mb-lg-0">
<label class="">From :</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="fe fe-calendar lh--9 op-6"></i>
                </div>
            </div><input class="form-control fc-datepicker" placeholder="11/01/2019" type="text" id="datepicker" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group mb-lg-0">
        <label class="">To :</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="fe fe-calendar lh--9 op-6"></i>
                </div>
            </div><input class="form-control fc-datepicker" placeholder="11/08/2019" type="text" id="datepicker1" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mi tarifa es de 20€ la hora o fracción. Si el precio te parece mal prueba a buscar a un programador freelance en ... ya sabes, páginas para programadores freelance. Si quieres que te echemos un cable aquí, expón el problema de manera apropiada, intenta presentar un código limpio, indica qué **errores** tienes, y sobre todo, expón **qué has intentado**. Para evitar que tu pregunta acabe cerrada te recomiendo leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Si estás usando Bootstrap, deberías ver los ejemplos de cómo utilizar los Grid. Otra vía podría ser: agregarle un id a cada div, por ejemplo: div_1 para el primero y div_2 para el segundo y, luego cambiar los estilos: `#div_1,#div_2 {float: left;}#div_1 {margin-right: 30px;}`, el margen derecho no es obligatorio, es para que no te salgan pegados los div. Si me permites darte un consejo, si estás utilizando Bootstrap, trata de explotarlo al máximo.